# How often should I get a new service sid of twillio?

Tags: node.js, express, twilio, twilio-api

When using twillio, how often should the service sid be created and create a new services? I see 3 options. There might be more options thought.

1. Get the service sid/create a new service and store it in the db, then never get a new one.
2. Get the service sid/create a new service every time the backend server starts/runs (I'm using node/express)
3. Get the service sid/create a new service whenever using the twillio client is used

Here's the code:

```
let serviceSid = '';
async function init() {
    const service = await client.verify.services.create({
        friendlyName: 'someName'
    });
    serviceSid = service.sid;
}
```

Also, what's the purpose of it, if you already have an account sid?

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/service

Comment: @AlexBaban So it's basically meant to set certain settings. And it should therefore run one time on server start, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Twilio ACCOUNT SID together width AUTH TOKEN has to do with your overall Twilio account. It gives you access to the entire Twilio API (Verify is just a part of it).

```js
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

To use the Twilio Verify product (or service if you wish) you will need to create at least one "verification service". You can do it in the Twilio console or by making API requests.

When you create a verification service you get that SID which starts with "VA" and it will be used in a verification code for example.

```js
client.verify.services('VAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
             .verifications
             .create({to: '+15017122661', channel: 'sms'})
             .then(verification => console.log(verification.sid));
```

If let's say you have more than one application using Verify you'll want to create a verification service for each application.

Also, maybe the verification message template is different or maybe you expect different lengths for the verification code, etc. then you need separate verification services hence different VA SIDs.

So from your options in your question I would go with number 1 per distinct application. If you only have one app then I would get one verification service per environment (one for dev, one for QA, one for production, etc.).

Also, I would create Twilio sub-accounts for each app + environment and use them instead of the Twilio master account.